# Docker - Extracting/Pull very slow

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying out docker on Windows 10 `Bash on Ubuntu (20.04)`. The Extracting is taking so much time even for 100Bytes of data.

Any idea how I can speed up Extracting and Pull? I'm unable to use Docker Desktop as I want to run other programs on Windows which consumes more memory.

```
root@DESKTOP-12341TV:/mnt/c/Users/username/manageiq_old/manageiq# docker build -t manageiq_lasker .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  44.56MB
Step 1/16 : ARG IMAGE_REF=latest
Step 2/16 : FROM manageiq/manageiq:latest-lasker
latest-lasker: Pulling from manageiq/manageiq
ccedeed05e42: Already exists
614980cc4ef1: Already exists
de4a343f807b: Already exists
a18424e88696: Already exists
1dd05e9407be: Already exists
b8ccac66c426: Already exists
88b5f00466d6: Already exists
c1f52454372d: Already exists
e0ede8e4b377: Extracting [==================================================>]     560B/560B
8bad32e02988: Download complete
4ac7122a57bb: Download complete
cc57113209fa: Download complete
1616660a8300: Download complete
d73927442680: Download complete
e8c7f40216ad: Download complete
4ca545ee6d5d: Download complete
a562ee696114: Download complete
ea9fc79e29c9: Download complete
5d767fd1acf1: Download complete
a9a20ffaec83: Download complete
130863a108a0: Download complete
b5dae5149024: Download complete
```

Answer (score 0):

See a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/877541/aws-instance-docker-pull-extract-is-very-slow). Summary of answers: Check the IO to see if it is being throttled in anyway.